# powershell open url in a hidden window except IE

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I would like to run a power shell command like Start-Process with browsers except IE to open in a hidden window. Is there any way to set size of browser to make it hidden when we run the powershell command.

Like; Start-Process -SomeCommandToOpenChromeHidden "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"

Any idea?

Thanks

**RESOLVED:**
I updated my IE to 11 then now it is fine with following command:

```
$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application $ie.visible = $false
```

Answer (score 1):

There is -WindowStyle Parameter. Values can be: Normal, Hidden, Minimized, and Maximized. The default value is Normal.

So you need to use:

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"
```