# Start Chrome Minimized?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, shortcut

`rundll32 shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL "C:\...\shortcut.lnk"`

`rundll32 shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL "C:\...\shortcut2.lnk"`

That's what I've got so far running inside a batch. It starts Chrome just fine, but I want it to start minimized as I only want a page to autorun and then Chrome be closed later automatically. I don't ever want the window to be anything other than minimized.

So far I've tried /min in every location of this command that I could and none have worked. The only position where it does anything is before the directory and it seems to run the Chrome process and then kills it immediately after. Putting --no-startup-window as a parameter in the shortcut also reacts the same way.

I've tried a few other things as well like setting the shortcuts to "minimized" in the window mode, but nothing has worked so far. I could really use some help with this as I'm pretty much stuck. The solution could either be a command for a batch executable or something having to do with the actual shortcut file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'd hate to have to manually minimize these two windows every day.

Here are the two shortcuts and batch file if you want to mess with them.
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_KZqubEguX6N04xOVZfWVVlQUE

Comment: `start "" /MIN chrome`?

Comment: `start "" /MIN "C:\Portable Apps\Program Files\Google Chrome\GoogleChromePortable.exe"`

Didn't work. Started windowed.

Comment: If you want to open a link without a window to appear, you can think about starting chrome as a background service without desktop interaction. At the Windows side, batch itself hasn't the tools for that.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need to run Chrome from a bat file with non full screen mode you can try to use these parameters:

```
--window-position=0,0 --window-size=1,1
```

Comment: It's better to send it to the invisible area of the screen. Powershell: $chrome = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command').'(Default)'; $proc = Start-Process $chrome "$url --window-position=5000,0 --window-size=1,1" -WindowStyle Minimized -passthru

Answer (score 1):

While thinking about a solution within a batch file and coming to the conclusion that there isn't a better solution, than also described above, I've written this quick and dirty piece of code and compiled it in case that you don't have a compiler:

(You will find it also as a [snippet on Gist](https://gist.github.com/Clijsters/e4e3c1a50cd0a8a654b8d39ee353fb64))

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main(ByVal Args() As String)
        Try
            If Args.Length = 2 Then
                Dim fileName As String = Args(1)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) Then
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
                        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(fileName)
                        Select Case Args(0).ToLower()
                            Case "hide"
                                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                            Case "minimize"
                                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
                            Case Else
                                Console.WriteLine(Args(0) & " is unknown. Showing Window.")
                                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
                        End Select
                        Process.Start(startInfo)
                    Else
                        Throw New System.IO.FileNotFoundException("The file specified was not found. (""" & fileName & """)")
                    End If
                Else
                    Throw New System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("No file specified.")
                End If
            Else
                Throw New System.Exception("Invalid count of arguments")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception 'Optional: Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
            Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            End
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Download the compiled file: [RunProcess.exe](http://demo.xylo-it.de/2-Codes/RunProcess.exe).

For those who aren't familiar with vb.net or don't want to read this bad formatted thing:

You can use it the following way:

```
RunProcess minimize "C:\Program Files\[...]\chrome.exe"
RunProcess hide "C:\Program Files\[...]\chrome.exe"
RunProcess show "C:\Program Files\[...]\chrome.exe"
```

At this point it doesn't check execute paths:

`RunProcess minimize "cmd.exe"` wont work. You would have to use `RunProcess minimize "%systemroot%\System32\cmd.exe"`

**EDIT:**

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849631/powershell-open-url-in-a-hidden-window-except-ie): `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"`

Comment: When i run RunProcess.exe its asking to windows .Net framework. That is like extra hassle. Can you make the RunProcess.exe like without any dependencies? So that user clicks and its done.

Comment: Tried `RunProcess` but it does not work in 2017 Aug. Messed up tool. Not reliable and stable solution at all.

Comment: @YumYumYum, Sure! That's why it's called a _quick and dirty piece of code_, it's just for instruction, one can write the nearly same thing in most other languages like Java, Mono C#, cpp with less dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want them to stay open for very long you could do like this

```
start "C:\Portable Apps\Program Files\Google Chrome\GoogleChromePortable.exe" <somelink1>
start "C:\Portable Apps\Program Files\Google Chrome\GoogleChromePortable.exe" <somelink2>
Taskkill /F /IM GoogleChromePortable.exe
```

or

```
Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
```

Comment: @FranzKurt I proposed this as I thought it could be a solution to what OP stated here "I only want a page to autorun and then Chrome be closed later automatically"